# Runtime exception at 0x004000b8: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x1001005a

Tags: assembly, memory, mips

I have a task to build a calculator in mips and I need to get symbol from the user and use this operand for calculation. I save the operands in the data and I want to get them to compare. I don't know what Im doing wrong but that's not working.

```
.data

IfStart: .asciiz "Start Calculator? (0: no, 1: yes):"
msg: .asciiz "Enter operation symbol (+, -, *) or ‘!’ to quit:"
mulb: .asciiz "*"
addb: .asciiz "+"
subb: .asciiz "-"
stopsign: .asciiz "!"
newline: .asciiz "\n"
pick1: .asciiz "Enter first number (A):"
pick2: .asciiz "Enter second number (B):"
badnumber: .asciiz "Bad input\n"
bye: .asciiz "Good bye!"
one: .word 1
result: .asciiz "The result is:"
buffer: .space 20

.text

main:

li $v0,4 
la $a0,IfStart
syscall

li $v0,5 #get number from user
syscall 

move $t0,$v0


lw $t1, one

beq $t1,$t0,if1
beq $zero,$t0,if0

li $v0,4 
la $a0,badnumber
syscall

li $v0,4 
la $a0,bye
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall

if1: 
jal Calculator

if0:
li $v0,4 
la $a0,bye
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall



Calculator:

li $v0,4 #print first message
la $a0,msg
syscall

li $v0,8 #take in input
la $a0, buffer #load byte space into address
li $a1, 20 # allot the byte space for string
move $t2,$a0 #save string t2
syscall

li $v0,5 #Read int A
syscall 

move $t0,$v0 #t0 is A

li $v0,5 #Read int B
syscall 

move $t1,$v0 #t1 is B

lw $t3, mulb #mul sign
lw $t6, subb #sub sign
lw $t4, stopsign
lw $t5, addb #add sign




beq $t3,$a0,stop
beq $t4,$a0,multp
beq $t5,$a0,adds
beq $t6,$a0,subbs

multp:
jal Multiply
j print

adds:
jal Sum
j print

subbs:
jal Substract

print:
li $v0,4 #print the result is:
la $a0,result
syscall

#print result
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall

li $v0,4 #print new line
la $a0,newline
syscall

jal Calculator
stop:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

After running one of this this rows:

```
lw $t4, stopsign  
lw $t5, addb #add sign
```

Its always keep write to me this error:
`Runtime exception at 0x004000b8: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x1001005a`

But the similar rows:

```
lw $t3, mulb #mul sign  
lw $t6, subb #sub sign
```

Have no problem at all.
Is it the chars that do the problem(!/+)?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: First, you're using `lw` with byte data, which is a mismatch.

Comment: Second, either we don't see  you're whole program, or, you're missing a proper halt sequence.

Comment: @ErikEidt Hi, thanks for replying. I add my whole code that relevent.
I would like to know why lw not fir here? its work for read the char "*" and "-" but not good for the other two?
Also, I've try to go back but its not give me any new breakout so I'm looking for help here.

Comment: `.byte1`, `.ascii`, and `.asciiz` are all for declaring byte data.  There's no alignment assistance, for example.  Since the data is bytes, `lw` does not make sense.  `lw` loads 4 consecutive bytes as a single number into a register.  You either want `lb` to load one byte, or `la` to load a pointer that refers to the string.  If using `lw` "works" that is only by accident.  If you want to use `lw` then change the data to `.word '*'`, for example,. as that will also avoid the mismatch.  (On the other hand, you don't need data for '*', that can be done with load immediate, `li $t0, '*'`.)

Comment: @ErikEidt Thanks for the answer, I'm pretty new to mips and assembly. can I use li $t0, for any of this signs [ '+' , '-' , '!' ] ?

Comment: Yes, those are all character values, so 7-bit immediates or less; MIPS has a 16-bit immediate field so they will fit.

Answer (score 1):

There's a limitation that MIPS and other RISC CPUs have, and that limitation is alignment rules. (ARM and to a lesser extent Motorola 68000 are similar.) If you're using `lw` to load a 32-bit value, the address of that value needs to be a multiple of 4. Put more simply, it needs to end in 0, 4, 8, or C. Reading bytes, on the other hand, can be done at any address regardless of alignment.

```
la $t0,msg    ;load the address of "msg" into $t0
lb $t1,0($t0) ;load the "E" in "Enter operation symbol (+, -, *) or ‘!’ to quit:" into $t1
```

The reason using the correct load command is so important, *is that the CPU isn't aware of what type your data is.* When you use a `.word`, `.byte`, or `.asciiz` directive to input data, you're using the format that is most convenient to you, the programmer. However, by the time your source code is converted into an executable program, the type information of your data is lost. Suppose you had the following, and let's assume that the label "MyString" below is aligned to a multiple of 4 (that is, its address ends in 0, 4, 8, or C.

```
.data
MyString: .asciiz "123"
.text

la $t0,MyString
lw $t1,0($t0)
```

So what actually happened here is that the value `0x31323300` was loaded into `$t1` (assuming big-endian architecture but that's a whole different can of worms). This means that the string "123", and the integer `0x31323300` (in decimal, 825,373,400),
*have the same representation in your CPU's memory and are completely interchangeable.* By using `lw` on a string, you get a totally different entity than intended, even though the data itself hasn't changed at all!

Comment: Not all RISCs are like that, but yes many classic ones including MIPS and SPARC disallow unaligned accesses. 
 RISC-V allows unaligned loads/stores, although they're allowed to be super slow, implemented via a trap handler.

Comment: Most simulated MIPS CPUs are little-endian: MARS always, and QtSPIM on little-endian hosts.  Big-endian MIPS does exist, and might be more common in real hardware, so the example isn't wrong, just doesn't match what most beginners will see in their simulator.

Comment: True, there are commands for unaligned access but I believe you need to specifically use those commands when accessing unaligned memory or you'll get an alignment fault.

Comment: That's true of MIPS, but not RISC-V.  Or at least it was last time I checked, but it seems the standard changed at some point to allow implementations that don't handle unaligned load/store in hardware or transparently via a trap.

Comment: https://riscv.org/technical/specifications/ vol.1 V2019-12-13 says - *Changed description of misaligned load and store behavior. The specification now allows
visible misaligned address traps in execution environment interfaces, rather than just mandating invisible handling of misaligned loads and stores in user mode. Also, now allows
access exceptions to be reported for misaligned accesses (including atomics) that should not
be emulated.*  They were always allowed to be super slow,, handled only via a trap, and https://godbolt.org/z/eE3xxaM4n shows GCC uses byte load/store for small memcpy.